# Subtracting Dates in Mongo

Tags: php, mongodb

I am trying to substract two dates in MonoDB using the aggreation framework.

My code looks like this:

```
$ops = array(
    array('$project' => array("fieldMath" => 
    array( '$subtract' => array( 'new ISODate()', 'new ISODate("last_interacted_date")' )),

     )),
    array('$match' => array('fieldMath' => array('$gte' => 2),
    ),
     ),
);
$object -> aggregate($ops);
```

The problem is I'm getting an error that I am trying to substract 2 string.

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'MongoResultException' with message
>   'localhost:27017: cant $subtract aString from a String

`new ISODate` and the `last_interacted_date` are both `ISODate` objects.

**My goal** is to subtract a 'last_did_something' date from the date today, and return results for all queries that are within 2 days.

What am I doing wrong and how I can subtract dates?

Comment: Can you pinpoint exactly what you are trying to achieve by including some sample documents and the expected output?

Comment: Add above, basically I want all results in which the date today when subtracted is greater than 2 days.

Comment: You should be calculating the date "outside" of the query. You just have a regular query then, and no need to aggregate. You of course to this in PHP. It's not JavaScript but BSON. So you let the driver do the translation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you want to query for documents that have the `last_interacted_date` date field greater than or equal to the date two days ago, you need to create a new date object (2 days ago date) that you can use as your query comparison. The following demonstrates this:

```
$start = new MongoDate(strtotime( "-2 days"));
$ops = array(
    array("$match" => array(
       "last_interacted_date" => array("$gte" => $start)
       )
    )    
);
$object -> aggregate($ops);
```

---

You can use a nifty library called **[Carbon](http://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/)** that can help dealing with date/time in PHP much easier and more semantic so that your code can become more readable and maintainable:

```
// get the current time
$current = Carbon::now();

// subtract 2 days to the current time
$start = $current->subDays(2);

$ops = array(
    array("$match" => array(
        "last_interacted_date" => array("$gte" => $start)
        )
    )    
);
$object -> aggregate($ops);
```

Comment: Your answer almost works for me, but I need need the number of days because I need compare it to another variable.